# How to profile a scrapy python script?

Tags: python, profiling, scrapy

Taking the example script

```
import scrapy
from scrapy.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule
from scrapy.linkextractors import LinkExtractor

class MySpider(CrawlSpider):
    name = 'example.com'
    allowed_domains = ['example.com']
    start_urls = ['http://www.example.com']

    rules = (
        # Extract links matching 'category.php' (but not matching 'subsection.php')
        # and follow links from them (since no callback means follow=True by default).
        Rule(LinkExtractor(allow=('category\.php', ), deny=('subsection\.php', ))),

        # Extract links matching 'item.php' and parse them with the spider's method parse_item
        Rule(LinkExtractor(allow=('item\.php', )), callback='parse_item'),
    )

    def parse_item(self, response):
        self.logger.info('Hi, this is an item page! %s', response.url)
        item = scrapy.Item()
        item['id'] = response.xpath('//td[@id="item_id"]/text()').re(r'ID: (\d+)')
        item['name'] = response.xpath('//td[@id="item_name"]/text()').extract()
        item['description'] = response.xpath('//td[@id="item_description"]/text()').extract()
        return item
```

can anyone please let me know practically how to do profiling of this script ?

Thanks

Comment: I can use cProfile to get the profile data, but the stats is horrible to read and understand. `python -m cProfile /path/to/your/bin/scrapy crawl yourSpidername` . The result stats is hard to spot outstanding processing, even get the graph from the stats

Answer (score 1):

That depends on what you want to profile:

- If it is general debugging, see [Debugging Spiders](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/debug.html)
- If it is memory usage, see [Debugging memory leaks](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/leaks.html)
- If it is crawling rate and other statistics, see [Stats Collection](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/stats.html)
- If you want to interact with the spider at runtime, the [Telnet Console](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/telnetconsole.html) might be the way to go.

There is also [Logging](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/logging.html), of course.